# What are the master's degrees in engineering a bachelor in computer engineering can be admitted in?

Tags: masters, engineering

What are the masteral degrees or courses a bachelor's degree in computer engineering usually leads to? Other than computer engineering itself, that is.

Answer (score 2):

There are a plethora of the graduate programs, could which be taken into account by a grad with B.A.Sc. in computer engineering (CE), due to the interdisciplinary inherent of this field and considerable overlap between CE and many other majors. One might assert that ***the passed courses*** and ***the probable research experiences*** could pave the way toward some of the potential fields, noticeably.

If you are interested in/have passed courses about the electronics, computer engineer, CAD and VLSI and so no, you might be pursue a M.A.Sc. in **electrical & computer engineering**...

If you had some background in biological systems, bioinformatic, neural networks, implantable circuits for human body and so on, I can stress on **biomedical engineering**, as a potential graduate major for you...

If studying in the field of network and data transfer systems and architectures had been taken into account by you, putting aside ECE, you would be interested in **media studies** and related humanities...

You might be interested in robotics and had some experiences to work with them in view of algorithmic approaches or hardware-driven mechanisms. If so, **computer science** or **mechanical engineering** program could be fascinating for you...

I can continue this roster, as you wish!

Just clear your interests... The way itself will be emerged...

Best of luck